# Mockito incorrectly injecting string value

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito

I have created an object in my test class, testObj, and mockDao is a dao object that I have mocked.

Function to test is something like:

```
MyDao myDao;

String myFunc(String param1, String param2) {
    MyObj realObj = new MyObj("param1", "param2");
    return myDao.someFunction(realObj);
}
```

UnitTest class something like:

```
@Mock
MyDao mockDao;
@InjectMock
MyComponent component;

MyObj testObj = new MyObj("param1", "param2");

@Test
public void test() {
    Mockito.when(mockDao.someFunction(testObj)).thenReturn(“123”);
    String returnedValue = component.myFunc("param1","param2");
    Assert.assertEquals(returnedValue, "123");
}
```

this should not inject “123” in my actual class, since the object that is created in actual class (realObj) is different from the testObj.

However, this is injecting "123" and my test is passing. While ideally it should fail.

How is it possible that this injection is happening?

Comment: show this class `MyObj` equals and hashcode are overridden in this class ?

Answer (score -1):

You're not using any argument matcher in your mock setting, in this case Mockito should use the default one: any(), which does not any checks about how method has been invoked (it returns true in every case).

Try to: `Mockito.when(mockDao.someFunction(Mockito.eq(testObj)).thenReturn(“123”)`. In this case Mockito is going to use the equals method of the object, in your case is the object reference.

I suggest you if you need somethig like "Anything does not match the following", try to look at AdditionalMatchers of Mockito